# Vite React + TypeScript Lib import folders by separated

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite

I am creating a library for personal use.

It works correctly but from the index.ts file I am exporting everything from the hooks, components and pages folders.

But everything is unified and I would like to be able to import everything separately, that is:

```
import {} form 'test-services/hooks'
import {} form 'test-services/pages'
import {} form 'test-services/components'
```

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "test-services",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "./dist/test-services.umd.cjs",
  "module": "./dist/test-services.js",
  "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./dist/test-services.js",
      "require": "./dist/test-services.umd.cjs",
      "types": "./dist/index.d.ts"
    },
    "./dist/index.css": {
      "import": "./dist/index.css",
      "require": "./dist/index.css"
    }
  },
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@fireworks-js/react": "^2.10.7",
    "@types/node": "^20.8.7",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.0.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.3",
    "eslint": "^8.45.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.3",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.43",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.0.2",
    "vite": "^4.4.5",
    "vite-plugin-dts": "^3.6.0",
    "vite-plugin-lib-inject-css": "^1.3.0",
    "vite-tsconfig-paths": "^4.2.1"
  }
}
```

This is my vite.config.ts file:

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite"
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react"
import { resolve } from "path"
import dts from "vite-plugin-dts"
import { libInjectCss } from "vite-plugin-lib-inject-css"
import tsConfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(), dts({ include: "src" }), libInjectCss(), tsConfigPaths()],
  server: {
    open: true,
    port: 3001,
  },
  build: {
    emptyOutDir: true,
    copyPublicDir: false,
    lib: {
      entry: resolve(__dirname, "src/index.ts"),
      name: "TestServices",
      fileName: "test-services",
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ["react", "react-dom"],
      output: {
        globals: {
          react: "React",
          "react-dom": "ReactDOM",
        },
      },
    },
  },
})
```

This is my entry file "index.ts":

```
import './App.css';
import './index.css';
export * from './components';
export * from './hooks';
export * from './pages';
```

This is my folder distribution:

```
src:
--/components
--/hooks
--/pages
--index.ts
```

What I'm doing wrong?

I'm receiving this error:

```
Cannot find module 'test-services/hooks' or its corresponding type declarations.
```